# How to clip items in a layer list drawable with respect to corner radius defined from another item

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, layer-list

As shown in the image below i cannot clip the corners of a layer corresponding to another layer. Is there any way that it can be done that I am missing here? I want to clip anything that's going out of the corner radius.

[image: Unintended extra from one of the layers]

**Here is the XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/darkColor">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/color_e95252" />
        <corners android:radius="16dp"/>

    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/lightColor1"
    android:bottom="40dp"
    android:right="300dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/color_ea5f5f" />
        <corners android:radius="16dp"/>

    </shape>
</item>

**The item below is kinda unnecessary**
<item android:id="@+id/lightColor2"
    android:right="90dp"
    android:top="-40dp"
    android:bottom="-10dp"
    android:left="10dp"
    android:width="300dp"
    >

  **This is where the problem occurs**


    <rotate android:fromDegrees="8">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/color_ea5f5f" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="300dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/dim_16"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>

</item>
```

Comment: add the values of dimen too.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, don't need that extra xml.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/darkColor">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/appThemeColor" />
            <corners android:radius="16dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/lightColor1"
        android:bottom="30dp"
        android:right="300dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


        </shape>
    </item>


    <item android:id="@+id/lightColor2"
        android:top="-50dp"
        android:width="300dp"
        >


        <rotate android:fromDegrees="8">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
                <corners
                    android:bottomRightRadius="250dp"
                    android:topLeftRadius="60dp"
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: the problem is if I rotate the lighter drawable it will not be clipped at the corners or the darker color drawable.

Comment: i might got it wrong, is there something behind red rectangle?

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA i have updated the code and image, you may check now.